# Stripe - Apply coupon to customer or subscription?

Tags: stripe-payments

In the Stripe API Documentation, they show that you can apply a coupon on a Customer.

```
cust = Stripe::Customer.retrieve("cus_asdasdad")
cust.coupon = "COUPONCODE"
cust.save
```

However, you can also apply a coupon on a Subscription:

```
cust = Stripe::Customer.retrieve("cus_asdasdad")
sub = cust.subscriptions.retrieve("sub_blablabla")
sub.coupon = "COUPONCODE"
sub.save
```

What is the difference between the two?  Essentially, I'd like to give a customer $15 off their next subscription charge, and only the next one.

Comment: for such questions you should ask the concerned team. e.g. stripe in this case

Answer (score 11):

To make a coupon that can only be used once set the `max_redemptions` property to 1.

With regard to your question, the difference is that applying the coupon to the **Customer** will apply the discount to the sub-total of the **Invoice** created for that **Customer**. Meaning that if the Invoice includes a **Subscription** and multiple **InvoiceItems**, then the discount will be applied to the sum of all of them.

Conversely, applying the coupon to a **Subscription** only means the discount will be applied to the cost of the **Subscription** only. Other **InvoiceItems** within the Invoice will not be discounted.

Won't make a difference if the Coupon is a "20 dollars off" type, but it will if it's a "20% off" kind.

Answer (score 5):

A coupon applied to a customer will apply to all future invoices and/or subscriptions, even if the coupon has expired, dependent upon how you set the duration attributes for the coupon.

A coupon applied to a subscription will only apply to that specific subscription.

The duration attribute will determine how long this discount will apply, either once, repeated, or forever.

The max_redemptions attribute limits the the total number of coupons that you are willing to honor, e.g. the first 100 customers.

Answer (score 1):

as it was already answered by others a coupon applied to the customer will affect every InvoiceItem not only the Subscription (in opposite to the case when you are applying coupon to the Subscription)

you should use `max_redemptions` property to limit the coupon applications number

if you need more customization you should probably use Stripe [PromotionCodes](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/discounts/codes) altogether with the Coupons
this will give you the ability to apply the discount to many customers, but only once per customer ([check here](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/discounts/codes#limit-redemptions))

another thing to mention regarding the difference between applying coupon to the customer and to the subscription is the next one:

- you can have cases in your flow (we have such a cases in our app) when you need to cancel current subscription for the customer and create a new one for the same customer
- in this case coupon (actually discount) applied to the customer, not to the subscription, will take effect even after this subscription renewal
- but in the case when the coupon was applied to the subscription the customer will loose his discount on such subscription cancellation/recreation

you can find more info regarding the question in the [Stripe docs](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/discounts)